# 404 Not Found for localhost:8080/actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've created a simple Boot application with web & actuator dependencies 
and I can't get `localhost:8080/actuator` and  got the following error in the browser:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>    :  This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are 
>       seeing this   as a fallback.
>       Fri Feb 03 19:02:01 CET 2017
>       There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>       No message available

Answer (score 2):

As the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints) states, the `/actuator` endpoint:

> Provides a hypermedia-based “discovery page” for the other endpoints.
>   **Requires Spring HATEOAS to be on the classpath**.

So you should add the `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` starter package in order to make the `/actuator` endpoint working. For example if you're using Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // web and actuator and others
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
}
```

Also you should set the `endpoints.hypermedia.enabled` property to `true`, as the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoint-hypermedia) says:

> If `endpoints.hypermedia.enabled` is set to `true` and Spring HATEOAS
>   is on the classpath (e.g. through the `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` or
>   if you are using Spring Data REST) then the HTTP endpoints from the
>   Actuator are enhanced with hypermedia links, and a “discovery page” is
>   added with links to all the endpoints. The “discovery page” is
>   available on `/actuator` by default.